# Ionic picture showing ERR_INVALID_URL

Tags: image, ionic-framework, camera, base64

Hi ionic I am trying to show pictures but I am getting ERR_INVALID_URL error. Here's the code

```js
 resimekle()
  {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }
    
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
     // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
     // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
     this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
     this.base64Image= this.base64Image.replace(/^file:\/\//, '');
    }, (err) => {
     // Handle error
    });
  }
```

```
<img [src]="_DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(base64Image)"/>
```

ERROR:  data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/1542647016224.jpg net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Answer (score 0):

Use File plug-in as below.

```
    this.file.readAsDataURL(path, fileName).then(imageBase64 => {
        this.picture = imageBase64;
      });

 <img src="{{picture}}">
```